# Tomcat 8.5 hot deploy lost connection with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, tomcat, tomcat8, spring-data-elasticsearch

In my test environment, I am running tomcat and I do hot deployment. This works most of the time, but there are rare occasion wherein the connection between tomcat and Elasticsearch gets lost. In my other application with tomcat and Elasticsearch (different version of Elasticsearch), I still encounter the same issue.

Usually, I just restart tomcat and it will establish the connection with Elasticsearch again. So in my other application, I stop tomcat before deploying the war file, then start it again. Since then, I am not getting this issue (lost ES connection) for that project. However, in the project that still uses hot deployment.. I am still getting this weird issue. If I do stop/deploy/start Tomcat, it will not have that issue, but I want this project to use hot deployment. I am thinking that tomcat should reestablish a connection with Elasticsearch, but this is not the case.

Anyone experienced this issue? and how did you manage to fix this hot deployment issue with Elasticsearch? By the way, I use spring data Elasticsearch and rest high level client Elasticsearch on different projects and both have the same issue on hot deploy (rarely happens though).